# C# Access app.config file in 3 layers architecture

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I'm making a small project using 3 layers architecture. I have read a topic in Microsoft forum that App.config file can only be access in GUI layer. My DAL(Data Access Layer) layer is class library project so I can't create App.config to store connection string. It's not true if I reference GUI project to DAL to access App.config file. So I have created a text file to store my connection string. But It's not safe.

Is there anyway to access App.config to get connection string?
Thanks!

Comment: Look up how to use `ConfigurationManager`. once you know enough about it, then look into encapsulating it behind an abstraction that can be injected into which ever layer you need it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's easy to get connection string from App.config by using ConnectionStrings property like this "ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString". Because like I said I used class library for my DAL layer so the class will be ".dll" file after rebuild. If I create DAL as Winforms project It's possible to get connection string. I'm still confused so can you give me an example. Thanks!